# Capybara tests fail while run in a bunch, but succeed while run separately

Tags: rspec, capybara

While running all my specs in a bunch using `bundle exec rspec` capybara keeps telling me that it can't find elements on page in number of tests.

Using `bundle exec rspec spec/features/feature_spec.rb` all goes normal.

**I tried to debug it using capybara-screenshot gem, but with this gem all specs are actually running good in a bunch.**

So I am curious what is happening?

**UPD**

This is part of my config:

```
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    if Capybara.current_driver == :rack_test # http://bit.ly/YZzrY5
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    else
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    end

    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```

Comment: You might want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/20428451/1008891

Comment: Are you using selenium or capybara-webkit by any chance? If so you may need to use a truncation strategy instead of transaction.

Comment: @RobertH, Look at my config above, please.

Comment: I just ran into this issue, and I had race conditions with feature tests that would re-create the same Devise user. Make sure your tests do not step on each other's toes.

Comment: Further to the suggestion @tiradc made, the '--bisect' flag in rspec is invaluable in determining which non-failing test(s) might be responsible for the discrepancy between suite/individual successes and failures:  [relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/bisect](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/bisect)